# Reflections on subspaces of $\text{codim} > 1$

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, root-systems, reflection-groups

Let $V$ be a real finite-dimensional vector space with inner product $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$.

Let $x,y \in V$ be linearly independent. I was wondering how a reflection $s_{x,y}$ through the $\text{codim} = 2$ subspace $H_x \cap H_y$ could be defined, where $H_v := \langle v \rangle^\bot$. I noticed that the following construction leads to a reasonable result:

1. Project $a \in V$ orthogonally onto $H_x$ $\Rightarrow$ $\pi_x(a) \in H_x$.
2. Reflect $\pi_x(a)$ through $H_x \cap H_y < H_x$ $\Rightarrow$ $s_{\pi_x(y)}(\pi_x(a)) \in H_x$.
3. Reverse project $s_{\pi_x(y)}(\pi_x(a))$ back from $H_x$

Here, $\pi_x(a)= a-cx$, $s_x(a)= a-2cx$ where $c= \frac{\langle x,a \rangle}{\langle x,x \rangle}$.

In total, we get the neat formula
$$s_{x,y}(a)= a - 2 \left(\frac{\langle x,x\rangle \langle y,a\rangle - \langle x,y\rangle\langle x,a\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle \langle y,y\rangle -\langle x,y\rangle^2}y  + \frac{\langle y,y\rangle \langle x,a\rangle - \langle y,x\rangle\langle y,a\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle \langle y,y\rangle -\langle x,y\rangle^2}x \right).$$
It is symmetric, scale invariant and satisfies $s^2=1$.

Similarly, we can define $s_{x,y,z}$ and so on. The construction is straight forward enough to assume that it is well-known, so I didn't make the effort to figure out the general formula for $s_{x_1, \dots,x_n}$.

So my question would be, is a general formula known and where can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found too late that this question is probably better off at MSE. However, for the sake of completeness and since I didn't find the formula in the literature, I will put it here:

$$s_{x_1, \dots, x_n}(a) = a - 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\langle x_1 \wedge \dots \wedge x_i \wedge \dots \wedge x_n,  x_1 \wedge \dots \wedge a \wedge \dots \wedge x_n\rangle}{|x_1 \wedge \dots \wedge x_n|^2} x_i. $$
Here, $\langle a_1\wedge \dots \wedge a_k , b_1 \wedge \dots \wedge b_k \rangle = \det (\langle a_i , b_j \rangle)_{i,j}$ is the [induced inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator#Formal_definition_for_k-vectors) on $\bigwedge^k(V)$.

If I'm not mistaken, we can write
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \langle x_1 \wedge \dots \wedge x_i \wedge \dots \wedge x_n,  x_1 \wedge \dots \wedge a \wedge \dots \wedge x_n\rangle x_i = \delta \left ( \partial(x \otimes a^{\flat})^{\flat} \right)(x),$$
where $\partial:\bigwedge^kV \otimes V^\vee \to \bigwedge^{k-1}V$ is the Koszul differential, $\delta = \partial^*$ and $x= x_1 \wedge \dots \wedge x_n.$

Comment: What is the inner product on $\bigwedge^n V$?

Comment: I added the definition